# Given a function $f$, find the largest $n$ such that $f(x)/x^n$ can be defined at $x=0$ to become differentiable there

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+1\right)+\cos x -1$. Find the largest $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that there is $C\in\Bbb{R}$ such that:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} &\mbox{if } x\ne 0 \\
C & \mbox{if } x=0 \end{cases} $$

Is differentiable at $x=0$. What is the value of $C$?

**My Work so far**
We know that
$$ln(t+1) = t - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{3} - ...$$

Hence,
$$\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + 1\right) = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8} + \frac{x^6}{24} + o(x^6)$$

$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720} + o(x^6)$$

Therefore,
$$f(x) = -\frac{x^4}{8} + \frac{x^4}{24} +o(x^5) = -\frac{1}{12}x^4 + o(x^5)$$

**The answer is $n=4$ but I'm not sure why.**

Comment: Why are you not sure? You've found the first nonzero term of the Taylor series, and that gives you the order with which $f$ vanishes at $0$ (and the constant $C$).

Comment: Note that $C=\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{8}$...

Comment: Divide by $x^4$ or a smaller power of $x$, things are nice. Divide by a higher power, the thing goes crazy at $0$.

Comment: So let $n$ to be arbitrary large and $C=0$. Isn't it works too?

Comment: I am confused :|